Why does removing instructions from my SSE intrinsic function make it slower?
Please note that this question is not about YUV422 to RGB conversion!
I have this code for a pixel order YUV422 to RGB conversion.
static void yuv422ToRGB(unsigned char* img,
  int width, int height, int widthStep, unsigned char* dst)
{

  __m128i yMask1 = _mm_setr_epi8(0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 8, -1, 8, -1);
  __m128i yMask2 = _mm_setr_epi8(8, -1, 12, -1, 12, -1, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
  __m128i uvMask1 = _mm_setr_epi8(1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 9, 11, 9, 11);
  __m128i uvMask2 = _mm_setr_epi8(9, 11, 13, 15, 13, 15, 13, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
  __m128i magicMask1 = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 102, 25, 52, -127, 0, 0, 102, 25, 52, -127, 0, 0, 102, 25, 52);
  __m128i magicMask2 = _mm_setr_epi8(-127, 0, 0, 102, 25, 52, -127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  __m128i const128 = _mm_set1_epi8(-127);
  __m128i const16 = _mm_set1_epi16(16);
  __m128i const32 = _mm_set1_epi16(32);
  __m128i const74 = _mm_set1_epi16(74);
  __m128i gFlipMask1 = _mm_setr_epi16(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1);
  __m128i gFlipMask2 = _mm_setr_epi16(1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 16)
    {
      __m128i imgreg1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(img + x));
      __m128i yValues1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, yMask1);
      yValues1 = _mm_subs_epi16(yValues1, const16);
      yValues1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(yValues1, const74);

      __m128i uvValues1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, uvMask1);
      uvValues1 = _mm_xor_si128(uvValues1, const128);

      __m128i toAdd1 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(magicMask1, uvValues1);
      toAdd1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(toAdd1, gFlipMask1);
      toAdd1 = _mm_add_epi16(toAdd1, const32);

      __m128i rgb1 = _mm_add_epi16(yValues1, toAdd1);
      rgb1 = _mm_srai_epi16(rgb1, 6);

      //======================

      __m128i yValues2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, yMask2);
      yValues2 = _mm_subs_epi16(yValues2, const16);
      yValues2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(yValues2, const74);

      __m128i uvValues2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, uvMask2);
      uvValues2 = _mm_xor_si128(uvValues2, const128);

      __m128i toAdd2 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(magicMask2, uvValues2);
      toAdd2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(toAdd2, gFlipMask2);
      toAdd2 = _mm_add_epi16(toAdd2, const32);

      __m128i rgb2 = _mm_add_epi16(yValues2, toAdd2);
      rgb2 = _mm_srai_epi16(rgb2, 6);


      //======================

      __m128i out = _mm_packus_epi16(rgb1, rgb2);
      _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(dst), out);
      dst += 12;
    }
    img += widthStep;
  }
}

I had an Idea to make it faster using an alternative calculation method that would require fewer instructions. To check how much performance I could gain, I uncommented six instructions inside the loop which might be saved. The rest of the code remained unchanged:
static void yuv422ToRGB(unsigned char* img,
  int width, int height, int widthStep, unsigned char* dst)
{

  __m128i yMask1 = _mm_setr_epi8(5, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 8, -1, 8, -1);
  __m128i yMask2 = _mm_setr_epi8(8, -1, 12, -1, 12, -1, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
  __m128i uvMask1 = _mm_setr_epi8(1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 9, 11, 9, 11);
  __m128i uvMask2 = _mm_setr_epi8(9, 11, 13, 15, 13, 15, 13, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
  __m128i magicMask1 = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 102, 25, 52, -127, 0, 0, 102, 25, 52, -127, 0, 0, 102, 25, 52);
  __m128i magicMask2 = _mm_setr_epi8(-127, 0, 0, 102, 25, 52, -127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  __m128i const128 = _mm_set1_epi8(-127);
  __m128i const16 = _mm_set1_epi16(16);
  __m128i const32 = _mm_set1_epi16(32);
  __m128i const74 = _mm_set1_epi16(74);
  __m128i gFlipMask1 = _mm_setr_epi16(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1);
  __m128i gFlipMask2 = _mm_setr_epi16(1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 16)
    {
      __m128i imgreg1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(img + x));
      __m128i yValues1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, yMask1);
      //yValues1 = _mm_subs_epi16(yValues1, const16);
      //yValues1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(yValues1, const74);

      __m128i uvValues1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, uvMask1);
      uvValues1 = _mm_xor_si128(uvValues1, const128);

      __m128i toAdd1 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(magicMask1, uvValues1);
      toAdd1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(toAdd1, gFlipMask1);
      //toAdd1 = _mm_add_epi16(toAdd1, const32);

      __m128i rgb1 = _mm_add_epi16(yValues1, toAdd1);
      rgb1 = _mm_srai_epi16(rgb1, 6);

      //======================

      __m128i yValues2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, yMask2);
      //yValues2 = _mm_subs_epi16(yValues2, const16);
      //yValues2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(yValues2, const74);

      __m128i uvValues2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(imgreg1, uvMask2);
      uvValues2 = _mm_xor_si128(uvValues2, const128);

      __m128i toAdd2 = _mm_maddubs_epi16(magicMask2, uvValues2);
      toAdd2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(toAdd2, gFlipMask2);
      //toAdd2 = _mm_add_epi16(toAdd2, const32);

      __m128i rgb2 = _mm_add_epi16(yValues2, toAdd2);
      rgb2 = _mm_srai_epi16(rgb2, 6);


      //======================

      __m128i out = _mm_packus_epi16(rgb1, rgb2);
      _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(dst), out);
      dst += 12;
    }
    img += widthStep;
  }
}

Profiling the modified version, it turns out it is around 10% slower than the original (~2.2ms vs 1.9ms). This doesn't make any sense to me. I was expecting that it might not make a difference because the bottleneck is somewhere else, but how can fewer instructions make the code slower?
What I've checked:

The compiler output https://godbolt.org/z/893c8EfPW
Effects of caching. I tested this call order: A A B B A B. All calls of A were faster than calls of B.

The Plattform:

Intel Atom E3845
clang 14
Compiler flags: -std=c++14 -O3 -march=silvermont

I tried to make a smaller example that shows the same behavior, but as soon as I change some parts of the code, e.g. only calculate yValues1, the anomaly vanishes.
How can this behavior be explained in a general way?

How many times did you run your profiler? There could be some degree of variance in the results from one iteration to another. Also have you tried maybe measuring the time using std::chrono? I've seen cases where the profiler may add overhead to your process so maybe you might want to try that.

Off the top of my head, not all SSE instructions have the same latency and cycles per instruction. Have you diffed for any documented performance differences?

@Valdez the measurement is done using std::chrono and the values are averaged over thousands of iterations. I triple checked my findings since I couldn't believe the results.
at AndyG this would make sense if I replaced certain instructions, but I only removed instructions

@Crigges how do the two dissassemblies look like? I would imagine that they should look close with the only difference being the number of lines, however sometimes I've experienced the compiler using a different instruction set than what I thought I was requesting (MSV compiler). Maybe you can catch the issue there.

@Valdez I've put them in the question https://godbolt.org/z/893c8EfPW

Just speculating, but according to Agner Fog Silvermont has terrible throughput and latency for pshufb (5 each) and pmaddubsw also has a latency of 5. It might be that the longer/faster variant just happens to be better suited for out-of-order execution (which probably was not that advanced on that CPU).

@Crigges You can make diff views on godbolt : https://godbolt.org/z/joE1zb1da

llvm-mca claims your reduced version should be 10% faster: https://godbolt.org/z/x154z6Eax (only looking at the inner loop). Are you sure about your benchmark code?

@chtz I just benchmarked the code again and the findings are the same. The code with the removed instructions is at least 10% slower. I will try to make a smaller example that shows the same behavior and update the question.

@Crigges, yes if you post your benchmark code, maybe someone can spot an issue with that. Also, can you tell how large your inputs are (or how many cycles/pixel each code takes)?
